# How to add number of days to today's date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I need to be able to add 1, 2 , 5 or 10 days to today's date using jQuery.

Answer (score 646):

You can use JavaScript, no jQuery required:

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
var result = someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
console.log(new Date(result))
```

Comment: Like most things javascript, the built-in date processing is extremely powerful, but completely non-intuitive.

Comment: @Joel: agreed, it's a headshaker that `setDate()`. Non-intuitive is a good descriptor.

Comment: [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) for reference.

Comment: @Joel: that problem is not exclusive to JavaScript. Date/Time API are traditionally a bit weird.

Comment: how do i get it in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Comment: Just for documentation, you can add o substract days with the method `setDate`. It does not matter if the number you pass to the method is greater than 31, it could be even a negative value.

Comment: @Thilo: probably the final proof that humans have some problems in defining what is *time* ;)

Comment: I wouldn't call this *dd/mm/yyyy* format. I call this *d/m/yyyy*.

Comment: I'd +1 this 1000 times if I could.  My little workaround for the dd issue is:

if(dd < 10)
{
dd = "0" + dd;
}

Comment: For your formatting to dd/mm/y, isn't this a primitive addition? If `someDate` is 2013-12-31 and you add a month, won't this make the date  2013/13/31?

Comment: @jake No, it won't. `.getMonth()` returns a zero-based value for the month. So in your example, December would be returned as 11. The user would expect that it be 12, so we add 1 to the value returned by JavaScript.

Comment: If you have some troubles with adding days (which is the value of a <select> for exemple), this is because of the "numberOfDaysToAdd" type which is a string so add the parseInt() function to your var.

Comment: Apparently, you shouldn't use setDate directly because it's a mutator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime

Comment: I put this in a slightly different format: mm/dd/y :P

Comment: How can I add numberOfDaysToAdd value dynamically..

Comment: it will gets wrong when you add like 25+14 ?

Comment: To get Yesterday do this `d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);`

Comment: An annoying gotcha: `.setDate()` returns an integer, and _not_ the underlying modified date object. So you can't use it for in-place mutation, like `{ cookieExpiry: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 30) }`

Comment: If this method is returning the wrong date, try casting the number of days to add to an integer (using `parseInt()`)

Answer (score 172):

This is for 5 days:

```
var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(5*24*60*60*1000));
```

You don't need JQuery, you can do it in JavaScript, Hope you get it.

Comment: I think this is by now the most clean solution I found. Thanks

Comment: To expand furthermore, to add 180 minutes `new Date(new Date().getTime()+(180*60*1000))`

Comment: Or, to simplify further, for 5 days:
`let myDate = new Date(Date.now() + 5 * 86400000);`

Comment: leap seconds, DST - won't work

Comment: This works like charm for me for date part.

Comment: this is soo classy!! thanks!

Answer (score 114):

You could extend the javascript Date object like this

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(days));
    return this;
};
```

and in your javascript code you could call

```
var currentDate = new Date();
// to add 4 days to current date
currentDate.addDays(4);
```

Comment: That will not work... adding days will get weird years and months as result.

Comment: @Ferryvandenheuvel: Not true. The proposed method works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ferryvandenheuvel was right because Krishnas solution needs a minor but important improvement to be safe if the days are given as string instead of an integer: see my comment below http://stackoverflow.com/a/20468397/2732083

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason without parseInt I would get strange results (months ahead) when adding dates, but subtracting days worked fine. How did you know to add parseInt?

Answer (score 88):

Why not simply use

```
function addDays(theDate, days) {
    return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}

var newDate = addDays(new Date(), 5);
```

or -5 to remove 5 days

Comment: To return a formatted date use this  **** return (returndate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + returndate.getDate() + "/" + returndate.getFullYear();

Comment: this would fail twice a year due to DTS change.

Comment: As per jancha comment regarding this function: Adding days over DTS boundary will give you Incorrect Date/Time result.  Thus, the best is to use established date library like momentjs.

Comment: @jancha To be more precise, the code consistently adds 120 hours to the UTC equivalent time -- this means, that twice a year, you would end up with a different hour-of-the-day in the result. This might be what you want, or it might not.

Answer (score 36):

#### [UPDATE] Consider reading [this](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) before you proceed...

**Moment.js**

Install `moment.js` from [here](http://momentjs.com/).

**npm** : `$ npm i --save moment`

**Bower** : $ `bower install --save moment`

Next,

```
var date = moment()
            .add(2,'d') //replace 2 with number of days you want to add
            .toDate(); //convert it to a Javascript Date Object if you like
```

Link Ref : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

`Moment.js` is an amazing Javascript library to manage Date objects

Good Luck.

Comment: 40kb is too much for a single page application and just for manage dates

Comment: 40kb is no problem, it will be cached in the browser, so download time will only apply on first page view. Users with broadband connection will not notice any difference.

Comment: @stackdave depends on the intensity. Just adding a few days, yes. Managing complex date logic, no.

Comment: Unfortunately momentjs has stopped working on the project and is in maintenance-only mode :(

Comment: @CularBytes, ! Where did you you read this?

Comment: I had the same response when I read this: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: @CularBytes, updated the answer.  Thanks :)

Comment: Why adding a library to perform such a simple task?

Comment: @BotondKopacz, I was answering the main question in the best way I knew at that point.

Answer (score 35):

Pure JS solution, with date formatted `YYYY-mm-dd` format

```js
var someDate = new Date('2014-05-14');
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 15); //number  of days to add, e.x. 15 days
var dateFormated = someDate.toISOString().substr(0,10);
console.log(dateFormated);
```

Comment: Excellent... esp. the way of formatting which perfectly works in my case, may not be a generic solution though.

Comment: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

(from the Mozilla ref)

Comment: when days value come dynamic then your code create the wrong date, please check

Answer (score 31):

The prototype-solution from Krishna Chytanya is very nice, but needs a minor but important improvement.
The days param must be parsed as Integer to avoid weird calculations when days is a String like "1". (I needed several hours to find out, what went wrong in my application.)

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(days));
    return this;
};
```

Even if you do not use this prototype function:
**Always be sure to have an Integer when using setDate().**

Comment: I had written the prototype function myself but it just wouldn't work when adding days and I could not figure it out. Adding parseInt solved this problem immediately. How did you think to use that? I never would've thought of that in a million years.

Answer (score 19):

If the times in the Date are not needed, then you can simply use the date object's methods to extract the Month,Year and Day and add "n" number of days to the Day part.

```
var n=5; //number of days to add. 
var today=new Date(); //Today's Date
var requiredDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+n)
```

Ref:[Mozilla Javascript GetDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

Edit: Ref: [Mozilla JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: If you run a getDate() function on requiredDate, the returned value with then be incorrect.

Comment: Not really @CyrilleArmanger : Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sahiljambhekar/6u7caake/ . Also on the variable 'requiredDate' if you run the getDate() method then it would return the Day of the Month,which comes in correct too. So please,remove the downvote as it's working code

Comment: What will happen when today.getDate() === 30?

Comment: @AlexPolkhovsky: Sorry for the late reply. In your case, it would roll over to the next month (if that month has 30 days). Ref: https://jsfiddle.net/sahiljam/jmty86xm/

Comment: this method cannot work. What happens if the date === 30

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer here gave me unpredictable results, sometimes weirdly adding months and years.

The most reliable way I could find was found here
[Add days to Javascript Date object, and also increment month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081500/add-days-to-javascript-date-object-and-also-increment-month)

```
var dayOffset = 20;
var millisecondOffset = dayOffset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
december.setTime(december.getTime() + millisecondOffset);
```

*EDIT: Even though it has worked for some people, I don't think it is entirely correct. I would recommend going with a more popular answer or using something like http://momentjs.com/*

---

Comment: This won't work for days with daylight savings changing. Some days aren't 24 hours a day, some are 23, some are 25. I don't know what unpredictable results you got but adding 1 to the day(date) property and let the library work out the rest is usually the best way.

Comment: If you are only interested in which **day** it is could use this solution make sure that the time is something like 12:00. You need to ignore the time of the result though, but the day should be correct.

Comment: What are the unpredictable results?

Comment: @Sam Sounds like "unpredictable results" == "adding 31 days adds a month"...at least that's what it sounds like to me from he comment.

Comment: @saluce, I know what you mean, but I don't think I've ever had such problems from the accepted answer's method.  I'm curious about whether there really were incorrect results or if this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

```js
function addDays(n){
    var t = new Date();
    t.setDate(t.getDate() + n); 
    var month = "0"+(t.getMonth()+1);
    var date = "0"+t.getDate();
    month = month.slice(-2);
    date = date.slice(-2);
     var date = date +"/"+month +"/"+t.getFullYear();
    alert(date);
}

addDays(5);
```

Comment: That's pretty Nice. Work for me

Answer (score 8):

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 );
    return dat;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this library "[Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)  open-source JavaScript Date Library".

Answer (score 4):

I've found this to be a pain in javascript.  Check out this link that helped me.  Have you ever thought of extending the date object.

[http://pristinecoder.com/Blog/post/javascript-formatting-date-in-javascript](http://www.stevenleath.com/blogengine.web/post/2011/03/09/How-do-I-add-subtract-days-in-javascript.aspx)

```
/*
 * Date Format 1.2.3
 * (c) 2007-2009 Steven Levithan <stevenlevithan.com>
 * MIT license
 *
 * Includes enhancements by Scott Trenda <scott.trenda.net>
 * and Kris Kowal <cixar.com/~kris.kowal/>
 *
 * Accepts a date, a mask, or a date and a mask.
 * Returns a formatted version of the given date.
 * The date defaults to the current date/time.
 * The mask defaults to dateFormat.masks.default.
 */

var dateFormat = function () {
    var token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
        timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
        timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
        pad = function (val, len) {
            val = String(val);
            len = len || 2;
            while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
            return val;
        };

    // Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
    return function (date, mask, utc) {
        var dF = dateFormat;

        // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
        if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
            mask = date;
            date = undefined;
        }

        // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
        date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
        if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");

        mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);

        // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
        if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
            mask = mask.slice(4);
            utc = true;
        }

        var _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
            d = date[_ + "Date"](),
            D = date[_ + "Day"](),
            m = date[_ + "Month"](),
            y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
            H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
            M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
            s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
            L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
            o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
            flags = {
                d:    d,
                dd:   pad(d),
                ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
                dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
                m:    m + 1,
                mm:   pad(m + 1),
                mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
                mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
                yy:   String(y).slice(2),
                yyyy: y,
                h:    H % 12 || 12,
                hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
                H:    H,
                HH:   pad(H),
                M:    M,
                MM:   pad(M),
                s:    s,
                ss:   pad(s),
                l:    pad(L, 3),
                L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
                t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
                tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
                T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
                TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
                Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
                o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
                S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
            };

        return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
            return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
        });
    };
}();

// Some common format strings
dateFormat.masks = {
    "default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
    shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
    mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
    longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
    fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
    shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
    mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
    longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
    isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
    isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
    isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
    isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
};

// Internationalization strings
dateFormat.i18n = {
    dayNames: [
        "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ],
    monthNames: [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ]
};

// For convenience...
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
    return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};
```

Comment: Dead link... Fortunately page was saved on [WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120329060501/http://www.stevenleath.com/blogengine.web/post/2011/03/09/How-do-I-add-subtract-days-in-javascript.aspx). Although, there isn't much useful information on the page than the answer, it's good to have a look at the referenced source.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this and don't need JQuery: [timeSolver.js](https://github.com/sean1093/timeSolver)

For example, add 5 day on today:

```
var newDay = timeSolver.add(new Date(),5,"day");
```

You also can add by hour, month...etc.
please see for more infomation.

Comment: ...but you do need timeSolver?

Answer (score 0):

I found that JavaScript can return a correct date when you use `new Date(nYear, nMonth, nDate);` with the over days of that month.
Try to see the result of a `dDate` variable when you use this:

`var dDate = new Date(2012, 0, 34);   // the result is 3 Feb 2012`

---

I have a SkipDate function to share:

```
    function DaysOfMonth(nYear, nMonth) {
        switch (nMonth) {
            case 0:     // January
                return 31; break;
            case 1:     // February
                if ((nYear % 4) == 0) {
                    return 29;
                }
                else {
                    return 28;
                };
                break;
            case 2:     // March
                return 31; break;
            case 3:     // April
                return 30; break;
            case 4:     // May
                return 31; break;
            case 5:     // June
                return 30; break;
            case 6:     // July
                return 31; break;
            case 7:     // August
                return 31; break;
            case 8:     // September
                return 30; break;
            case 9:     // October
                return 31; break;
            case 10:     // November
                return 30; break;
            case 11:     // December
                return 31; break;
        }
    };

    function SkipDate(dDate, skipDays) {
        var nYear = dDate.getFullYear();
        var nMonth = dDate.getMonth();
        var nDate = dDate.getDate();
        var remainDays = skipDays;
        var dRunDate = dDate;

        while (remainDays > 0) {
            remainDays_month = DaysOfMonth(nYear, nMonth) - nDate;
            if (remainDays > remainDays_month) {
                remainDays = remainDays - remainDays_month - 1;
                nDate = 1;
                if (nMonth < 11) { nMonth = nMonth + 1; }
                else {
                    nMonth = 0;
                    nYear = nYear + 1;
                };
            }
            else {
                nDate = nDate + remainDays;
                remainDays = 0;
            };
            dRunDate = Date(nYear, nMonth, nDate);
        }
        return new Date(nYear, nMonth, nDate);
    };
```

Comment: That isn't how you calculate a leap year - it nees to take account of % 4, % 100 and % 400 to be right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me.

```
function calduedate(ndays){

    var newdt = new Date(); var chrday; var chrmnth;
    newdt.setDate(newdt.getDate() + parseInt(ndays));

    var newdate = newdt.getFullYear();
    if(newdt.getMonth() < 10){
        newdate = newdate+'-'+'0'+newdt.getMonth();
    }else{
        newdate = newdate+'-'+newdt.getMonth();
    }
    if(newdt.getDate() < 10){
        newdate = newdate+'-'+'0'+newdt.getDate();
    }else{
        newdate = newdate+'-'+newdt.getDate();
    }

    alert("newdate="+newdate);

}
```