# Adding days to a date - date getting converted to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to add a certain number of days to a date, and I'm getting a strange issue:

```
var date = new Date();

var newdate = date.getDate() + $('#ddlDays option:selected').val();

date.setDate(newdate);
```

So if today is 09/29/2010, the Date is 29. But if a user selects "5" from ddlDays, it will assume I am adding strings together, adding 295 days to my date.

I was under the impression that javascript would assume they were integers? Does getDate() return a string instead of an integer?

How can I fix this?

Comment: debugging 101: var newdate = date.getDate() + $('#ddlDays option:selected').val();
alert(newdate);alert(typeof date.getDate());alert(typeof $('#ddlDays option:selected').val());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to add the selected value to the day of the month (i.e. 29 + 5), then you need to parse the string value into an int:

```
var newdate = date.getDate() + parseInt( $('#ddlDays option:selected').val(), 10);
```

But if you actually want a new date, rather than an int, as your result, you can do something like this:

```
date.setDate( date.getDate() + parseInt( $('#ddlDays option:selected').val(), 10);
```

Comment: Thanks. I always thought that when adding a number (getDate) and a string (val), JS would convert the string to a number and then add them, but I guess it's the other way around?

Answer (score 2):

It is `.val()` that is returning a String. You can use `.parseInt()` to convert to a Number.

```
var newdate = date.getDate() + 
                      (parseInt($('#ddlDays option:selected').val(), 10) || 0);
```

or

```
var newdate = date.getDate() + ~~$('#ddlDays option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the `getDate()` call doesn't return a string, but the `val()` call does.

You'll need to parse the string to an integer instead:

```
var newdate = date.getDate() + parseInt($('#ddlDays option:selected').val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround your string value with parseInt. JavaScript will concatenate strings to numbers (see http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference for a thorough run through.)

This should do the trick:

```
var newdate = date.getDate() + parseInt($('#ddlDays option:selected').val());
```

or

```
var newdate = date.getDate() + parseInt($('#ddlDays option:selected').val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

adding days and converting it to a specific format are talked about in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)