# Add day(s) to a Date object

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

I'm confused, I found so many different approaches, and which of them is actually correct?

So what is the correct way to add day(s) to a given Date?

Comment: Most of the ways you've found are probably correct

Comment: What are the approaches you found ??

Answer (score 133, accepted):

**Note** : Use it if calculating / adding days from current date.

**Be aware: this answer has issues (see comments)**

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + AddDaysHere);
```

**It should be like**

`var newDate = new Date(date.setTime( date.getTime() + days * 86400000 ));`

Comment: yeah, but what if I add more than 31 days?

Comment: It takes care of the logic for you. Flips to the next month, year, etc. It's pretty rad.

Comment: ^ +1 for using "rad" :D

Comment: +1 also a fan of "rad" :p

Comment: Fails if month or year are not the same...

Comment: This does not work!! It only changes the day value of the current month... Sorry, it's not rad. The getTime method by "Nobody" works.

Comment: Why do so many people accept this as the correct solution when, as suggested by others, it only works within the same month and year.

Comment: @KelsoSharp can you share an example where this fails? I tried adding 100 days and it worked, thanks

Comment: I tried adding 4 days to 2015-02-27 (as a date object) and it returned 2015-11-02

Comment: "If the dayValue is outside of the range of date values for the month, setDate() will update the Date object accordingly. For example, if 0 is provided for dayValue, the date will be set to the last day of the previous month." ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate))

Comment: It _does_ work, you know. Try `var d=new Date(); d.setDate(32); console.log(d);` It displays a time at the beginning of next month, as you would expect from the documentation I referred to in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.

Comment: Doesn't work at all when the month or year needs to be incresed as well!

Comment: @motagirl2 That's because it days a number of _days_ - convert your months and years to days and then try again

Comment: I tried the code above using the last day of this month (3/31/2019). My program needs to be able to calculate 30, 60, and 90 days out--I got the expected results (4/30/19, 5/30/19, and 6/29/19, respectively). My only criticism is it also adjusts the input date variable, so I'll need to re-code if I want to preserve the original date.

Comment: @Pizzor2000 what if you started with 11/30/2019. Would it still work?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО It still worked for me (Mon Dec 30 2009, Wed Jan 29 2020, Fri Feb 28 2020).

Answer (score 211):

```
date.setTime( date.getTime() + days * 86400000 );
```

Comment: This is what worked best for me working with _arbitrary_ dates.

Comment: +1 - `setDate` does not like adding days to a date, `setTime` is perfectly happy with adding number of days in milliseconds

Comment: This must be the accepted answer as it is the only correct answer.

Comment: You'll have to also cast this to a new date: var newDate = new Date(date.setTime( date.getTime() + days * 86400000 ));

Comment: This logic does not take Daylight Savings into account. If we cross a "move forward an hour" or "move back an hour" boundary, the result will not be aligned on day boundaries. The solution is to round to the nearest day boundary by adding 12 hours and zeroing out the hours like so: `date.setTime(date.getTime() + 12 * 1000 * 60 * 60); date.setHours(0);` (...If you can believe it, I basically started using my account in earnest just this evening and answered 4 questions just so I could get enough reputation to write this comment. It matters to me that much, because I just ran into this problem!)

Comment: Adding just 12 hours is not working when the time of the `date` object is before 12 AM. The date remains the same. The solution is first setting the hours to 22 for example, and then adding the 12 hours.