# How to Increment a day in Date using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have date object like this "Tue Sep 02 2014 13:34:17 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"
 I want increment a day in the date object using node.js.

```
I.E.
     var myDate = "Tue Sep 02 2014 13:34:17 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)";
```

please mention how to increment a day in above myDate.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add day(s) to a Date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963311/add-days-to-a-date-object)

Comment: I have tried this solution but in my case its giving me error. Error is getDate() method not found.

Comment: This is my code which i am using.      

var dateStartedTemp = new Date();

dateStartedTemp = dateStartedTemp.setDate( dateStartedTemp.getDate+1);

But its giving me error that getDate() method not found.

Comment: And Above solution which you reffered  is works in browser not in node.js

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var myDate = new Date("Tue Sep 02 2014 13:34:17 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)");
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
alert(myDate);
```

Comment: This solution is in browser not in node.js.