# how to find the date of week days based on current day

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I want to write a jQuery code, which calculates the date of upcoming week day.

It is for arranging the meetings. manager chooses the meeting days, with weekly period.  for example every Saturday. 
Employee looks into the meeting panel, and notifies when is the next meeting. 
it has to show the date, according to Today's date. and when it expired, again calculates it for the upcoming week.

the problem is that, I can't find the way to calculate the chosen day's date, correctly. I wrote this :

```
var d = $("#day").html();
var x = 0;

if (d === "Saturday") { 
    var x = 0;
};
if (d === "Sunday") { 
    var x = 1;
};
if (d === "Monday") { 
    var x = 2;
};

if (d === "Tuesday") { 
    var x = 3;
};
if (d === "Wednesday") { 
    var x = 4;
};
if (d === "Thursday") { 
    var x = 5;
};
if (d === "Friday") { 
    var x = 6;
};
var b = new Date();
var n = b.getDay();
var c = n - x;
```

now c is the difference between today and the upcoming meeting date.
for finding the date of meeting, I am going to use moment.js library like this

```
moment().add("day", x).toString();
```

but it is not returning the date for me. Do you have a better algorithm ?

Comment: Not sure I get it. are you just trying to get "next saturday" etc ?

Comment: Sunday - 0 and Saturday - 6...

Comment: @adeneo not exactly the Saturday.  it depends on the date they are going to choose when they are defining the meeting.

Comment: "I want to write a jQuery code". This is javascript, not jQuery. Please make sure you understand the difference. It's quite important.

Comment: I get that you don't always want Saturday, but it's a *"get the next someday"* question

Comment: jQuery !== JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
var d = $("#day").html();
var x = 0;

if (d === "Saturday") { 
    var x = 6;
};
if (d === "Sunday") { 
    var x = 0;
};
if (d === "Monday") { 
    var x = 1;
};

if (d === "Tuesday") { 
    var x = 2;
};
if (d === "Wednesday") { 
    var x = 3;
};
if (d === "Thursday") { 
    var x = 4;
};
if (d === "Friday") { 
    var x = 5;
};
var b = new Date();
var n = b.getDay();
var c = n - x;
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setDate(b.getDate() + c);

//newDate should now have your new date for the next meeting
```

Code for incrementing date taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963332/4028085)