# Date returns NaN after instantiation with a timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963311/add-days-to-a-date-object) , so what is did was :

```
let date = 1507135378538;

let date2 = new Date(date).getTime(); //NaN
let dateIn30Days = date2 + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);//NaN
```

What I'm doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: When I run this in Node 8, neither `date2` nor `dateIn30Days` are NaN.

Comment: Can not reproduce. Doesn't make sense creating `date2` which would return same value as date1 anyway

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Date#setTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) to set a time with [epoch/UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```js
let date = 1507135378538;
let date2 = new Date;

date2.setTime(date);
console.log(date2);                             // 2017-10-04T16:42:58.538Z

date2.setTime(date + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(date2);                             // 2017-11-03T16:42:58.538Z
```

Comment: I was having an issue with handling UNIX time returned from a database query, and formatting as date in JS. A piece of this solution did the trick for me. Particularly, assigning date to date2 with .setTime. Other, more direct attempts (such as assigning new Date(my-unix-time) would result in error.