# Reactjs DayPickerInput disabled days

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I have a DayPickerInput element from react-day-picker plugin and I don't know how to disable all days after a month(31 days) starting with current day. Any help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation could be a clearer.  This should do it for you:

```
<DayPickerInput
    value={moment(minDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
    dayPickerProps={{
        disabledDays: {
            after: new Date(2018, 3, 20),
        },
    }}
    onDayChange={day => console.log(day)}
/>
```

Replace the new Date(y, m, d) with your date.

[Edit per my comment]

Not all months are 31 days, if you literally want to add 31 days to the first of a month:

Source: [Add day(s) to a Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963311/add-days-to-a-date-object)

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + AddDaysHere);
```

Where "AddDaysHere" would be 31.

If you just want to insure there is no way to select a date next month, you could:

```
// There is probably a billion better ways to get the next available month, this is just basic
let currentMonth = 2;
let nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
if (nextMonth > 11) { nextMonth = 0;} // I believe javascript months start at 0.

Date(2018, nextMonth, 1)
```

Happy coding!

Comment: You could use `new Date()` with no arguments to get the current time from the client system clock and client timezone.

Comment: @Nick DuBois  thanks for your response, I checked also the documentation but my problem is that I don't know how to compute dynamically the date for 'after' statement, let's say disable all dates after 30days starting from current day.

Comment: Thank you so much - i was struggling with this issue and had no idea that the props wouldn't populate further down into daypicker from daypickerinput - they really should update their documentation