# Add days to Javascript Date object, and also increment month

Tags: javascript, date

Looking over the previous questions and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime-using-java-script/563470#563470) it appeared this should work :

```
var palindrome = new Date('2011-11-11');
var december = new Date('2011-11-11');

december.setDate(palindrome.getDate()+20); 
//should be december, but in fact loops back over to Nov 1st)
```

my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYT8q/21/)

is there a simple way to ensure that months are incremented correctly, or have I missed something obvious ?

Comment: `var day = 60 * 60 * 24; december.setTime(december.getTime() + (day * 20));` however I'm not sure how to add months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getMonth()` call returns a value between 0 and 11, where 0 is January and 11 is December, so 10 means November.  You need to increment the value by 1 when using it in a string.  If you simply output it as a string you'll see that it has the correct date.  Note I also had to change the starting date format.  It didn't seem to like `2011-11-11` so I made it `11/11/2011`.  http://jsfiddle.net/9HLSW/

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this:

```
var dayOffset = 20;
var millisecondOffset = dayOffset * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
december.setTime(december.getTime() + millisecondOffset);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, however you are *converting it to a string wrongly*.

`getMonth()` starts with **0** as January, and ends with **11** as December. So all you need to do is add 1 to the month like this:

```
alert(endDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (endDate.getMonth()+1) +"-"+ endDate.getDate());
```

Notice the *additional brackets* - cos you are performing a math operation while concatenating strings. You won't want to end up with "**101**" as the month.

To see whether you got the date correct, use `endDate.toDateString()` to display the date in a fully qualified name (i.e.: January - December).

```
alert(endDate.toDateString());
```

For more info on the Date object, check out [this section](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) in w3schools