# How to add days to the now date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
var myDate = new Date();
var endtime= new Date(myDate.getDate()+1,23:59:59);
alert(endtime);
```

why there is no value of the endtime? if i want to add 1 day 10 hours 50 minute 30 second to the now time, how to wirte the endtime code? thank you

Comment: check this thread [add-number-of-days-to-todays-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want..........

Answer (score 14):

Try one of the two way will work for you...

```
function addDays(myDate,days) {
return new Date(myDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}
```

## DEMO1


or

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
```

## DEMO2

Comment: why 24*60*60*1000 the last multiply number is 1000? thank you.

Comment: @250091017 because the value is in milliseconds (1000 milliseconds per second).

Answer (score 7):

You will need to add the days in milliseconds:

```
var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now() + 1 * 24*3600*1000);
```

Of course you can add various amounts of time, you just need to count it in milliseconds when using the Date constructor or set/getTime().

You can also set the different units one-by-one using their respective [`Date` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/):

```
var sometime = new Date; // now
sometime.setDate(sometime.getDate() + numberOfDays); 
sometime.setHours(sometime.getHours() + numberOfHours); 
sometime.setMinutes(sometime.getMinutes() + numberOfMinutes);
...
```

You can't set the Date with a float value, it will be truncated when beeing converted to an Integer.

But the setter methods higher than milliseconds and higher than date have optional attributes, so that you can combine the setting:

```
var sometime = new Date; // now
sometime.setFullYear(
  sometime.getFullYear() + numberOfYears,
  sometime.getMonth() + numberOfMonths,
  sometime.getDate() + numberOfDays
); 
sometime.setHours(
  sometime.getHours() + numberOfHours,
  sometime.getMinutes() + numberOfMinutes,
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
var date = new Date();
var numberToAdd = 1;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + numberToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always create 7 functions, to work with date in JS: addSeconds, addMinutes, addHours, addDays, addWeeks, addMonths, addYears.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/YHA8x/

How to use:

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.addWeeks(3));
```

This are the functions:

```
        Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds) {
            this.setSeconds(this.getSeconds() + seconds);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMinutes = function(minutes) {
            this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + minutes);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addHours = function(hours) {
            this.setHours(this.getHours() + hours);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
            this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addWeeks = function(weeks) {
            this.addDays(weeks*7);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMonths = function (months) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + months);
            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addYears = function(years) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear() + years);

            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };
```