# Ajax Calendar Extender for Textbox

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add number of days to today’s date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

I would like to check how to add 3 days to date() so that the user cannot select any date within 3 days from today. Below is my code....

```
    function checkDate(sender, args) {
        if (sender._selectedDate < new Date()) {
            alert("You cannot select a day earlier than today!");
            sender._selectedDate = new Date();
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateFromNow  = new Date();

dateFromNow = dateFromNow.setDate(dateFromNow.getDate()+3);

if(sender._selectedDate < dateFromNow){

//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.datejs.com/ (Its open source, contrary to the '.com').

You could then do:

```
if (sender._selectedData < Date.today().add(3).days()) { ... }
```

Also, according to [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

```
var minDate = new Date();
minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 3); 
if (sender._selectedData < minDate) { ... }
```