# set date in textbox on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two text boxes which hold from date and to date in my page. I have some buttons. When I click on the button 1day, the from date and to date should be set to today's date. When I click on the button 1 week, to date should be set to today's date and from date should be set to 1 week before today. Other buttons have similar functionality. How can I do that using jQuery or JavaScript? Please provide me with a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/DWUrh/3/)

```
            <div id="date">
              From: <input  type="text" size="6" name="date" id="from" class="tcal">
              To:   <input type="text" size="6" name="date1" id="to" class="tcal">
              <button id="1day"> 1 Day </button>
              <button id="month"> 1 Month</button>
              <button id="3month"> 3 Month</button>
              <button id="year"> 1 year</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: So you are asking to write code for you???

Comment: See my edited fiddle.

Comment: like this ??  http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/DWUrh/4/

Comment: yeah.. I want to set date instead of text.

Comment: <script>
function change(obj)
{
    t=new Date();
        if (obj.id=="1day")
    document.getElementById("from").value=new Date().toLocaleString()
}
</script>

 use change(this) in function call.this is not the complete version of your answer.but this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

Look at this demo -

[DEMO jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWUrh/9/)

```
   $('button').click(function(){
       id = $(this).attr('id');
       $('#to').val((new Date()).getMonth() + "-" + (new Date()).getDate() + "-" + (new Date()).getFullYear());   

       if(id == '1day'){
           $('#from').val((new Date()).getMonth() + "-" + ((new Date()).getDate()-1) + "-" + (new Date()).getFullYear());          
       }
       if(id == 'month'){
           $('#from').val(((new Date()).getMonth()-1) + "-" + (new Date()).getDate() + "-" + (new Date()).getFullYear());     
       }

       if(id == '3month'){
           $('#from').val(((new Date()).getMonth()-3) + "-" + (new Date()).getDate() + "-" + (new Date()).getFullYear());     
       }

       if(id == 'year'){
          $('#from').val((new Date()).getMonth() + "-" + (new Date()).getDate() + "-" + ((new Date()).getFullYear()-1));     
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use date Object

For ex :

```
$("#1day").click(function () {
$("#from").val(new Date().toString());
$("#to").val(new Date().toString()) ;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/DWUrh/7/

To move further read :

- [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime-using-javascript)
- [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

Related to format :

- [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @AnushaHoney So you got code right finally :) Good luck with project.