# convert string date in d/m/y format to date and sum X days

Tags: jquery, date-format

I'm reciving a string with a date in d/m/Y format, and what I need is to convert it to a date and sum X days to it

Comment: can you ask what is exacty the pint you are missing? I have a date, I want to sum 1 day to this date, and I'm completely unable to do it, where is exactly the problem?

Comment: can you please post an example of the value, showing the exact format you receive the date?

Comment: @Mark I guess I'm missing everything from the context to the code example.

Comment: where is the problem? can you re re read please? :)

Comment: The content is edited, dunno how to explain if now it stills hard tu understand what I'm trying to ask

Answer (score 1):

```
var ajaxDate = [populate with the date from ajax]
var date = new Date(ajaxDate);
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 1;

date.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Formatting to d/m/y :

```
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var y = date.getFullYear();

var dormattedDate = d + '/'+ m + '/'+ y;
```

from [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

Comment: date is not from today, it can be any date and it's inside a var.

Comment: okok sorry, trying right now :)

Comment: The problem is that I'm reciving the date in d/m/y format and I'm unable to sum a day I'm geting crazy

Comment: you mean as a string ?

Comment: yup sorry, i'm reciving it as a string

Comment: FYI providing a date to `Date()` in DD/MM/YYYY format will cause an error

Comment: @Rory i don't think so `var d = new Date(Date.parse("1/1/2013")); /* you get back a Date object */
Date {Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100}`

Comment: @alex I do: http://jsfiddle.net/j6B2y/

Comment: @Mark can you post a date you are getting back

Comment: @alex it's because the `Date` object constructor expects the format `MM/DD/YYYY` (amongst others). It'll work for dates like `12/01/2013`, although the date will be Dec 1st, not Jan 12th.

Comment: my thought too locale

Comment: I'm playing with dates like: 15/11/2013 how to sum one or X days to this date in jquery? is it possible? @alex?

Comment: im afraid the short answer is no. you have to convert in the 'backend' and receive it in a standarized way.

Comment: I was reaching this point and belive me, I can't belive this... but what to do... let's play then...

Comment: ok, fixed, and thanks to everybody