# assigning date values to input fields using date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a url parameter called commencing date in the format of dd-mm-yyyy.  I have input fields in my html field and I need to set dates to those input fields. I need to dates to be set like this. If the commencing date(url parameter string) is 01-01-2014 , the first input field should have the date of 15-02-2015. That means 1 month and 2 weeks later. Then the next input field should have the date 1 month and 2 weeks after the 15-02-2014. This should happen say 10 times. I am doing it using a for loop.I have assigned `jquery datepicker` for my input fields.

```
var initialDate = "01-01-2014";
var x;
for(x=1; x<= 10;x++){


   var dateArray = initialDate.split("-");
   var dateObj = new Date(dateArray[2],dateArray[1],dateArray[0]);
   dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth()+1);
   dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate()+14);  

   // Assign the new date value to input field.
   $("#dateOf_installment_"+x).val(dateObj.getDate()+"-"+dateObj.getMonth()+"-"+dateObj.getFullYear());

}
```

But this does not give me the required values. How to solve this problem, Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems with your code -

The Date object uses 0-11 instead of 1-12 for months Jan-Dec.  So when you set the month of the date object, you need to subtract 1 to set the correct month.  When you convert the month back to Jan-Dec 1-12, you'll need to add back the 1.

Also, I updated your code a little so that the loop will continue working correctly.  This loop goes 3 iterations, but should be expandable to 10.

Lastly, if your answers come out different then expected, this thread might be the cause of the issue.
[How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/bteL6138/

```
var initialDate = "01-01-2014";
var lastDate = initialDate;
var x;

for (x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
    var dateArray = lastDate.split("-");

    // sub 1 from month
    var dateObj = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1] - 1, dateArray[0]);

    dateObj.setMonth(dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
    dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 14);

    // add 1 for month
    lastDate = dateObj.getDate() + "-" + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dateObj.getFullYear();              

    $("#dateOf_installment_" + x).val(lastDate);
}
```

Comment: No problem, anytime :)