# Increment JavasScript date object for next month when days are increased?

Tags: javascript, date, getdate

Is there a simple solution to auto increment the month of the date object when days are added via `getDate`?

I need to add 2 days to a user supplied date, for example if the user's entered value is `2014-11-16` it returns `2014-11-18`.

I have this working in the  below example, but the problem is if a user supplies a date at the end of the month, for example `2014-11-30` it will return `2014-11-32` (November only has 30 days) instead of rolling into the next month, it should be `2014-12-02`.

It also does not increment to a new year as well.

```
 var actualDate = new Date(arrive);

        var year = actualDate.getFullYear();
        var monthy = actualDate.getMonth()+1;
        var days = actualDate.getDate()+2;
        var out = year + '-' + (monthy < 10 ? '0' : '') + monthy + '-' + days;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bubykx1t/

Comment: Javascript, Dates ... [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add number of days to today's date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `setDate()` method.

```
var actualDate = new Date(arrive);
actualDate.setDate(actualDate.getDate() + 2);
```

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime)

Comment: I get a TypError when trying to invoke add() on a date object.

Comment: @Aweary sorry should be `setDate()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create new Date objects based on the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. Since the number of milliseconds in a minute, hour, day, week are set we can add a fixed amount to the current time in order to get a time in the future. We can forget about what day of the month, or year it is as it's inherent in the number of milliseconds that have passed since 1970.
This will keep adjust to days months and years correctly.

```
var numberOfDaysToIncrement = 7;
var offset = numberOfDaysToIncrement * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var date = new Date();
var dateIncremented = new Date(date.getTime() + offset);
```