# How to get to yesterday's date in IMAGE url and LINK url?

Tags: javascript

I hace code for today's date in image url and link url, this:

In HEAD:

```
<script>

Date.prototype.toMyString = function () {
   //If month/day is single digit value add perfix as 0
    function AddZero(obj) {
          obj = obj + '';
          if (obj.length == 1)
              obj = "0" + obj
          return obj;
    }

    var output = "";
    output += this.getFullYear();
    output += AddZero(this.getMonth()+1);
    output += AddZero(this.getDate());

    return output;
}

var d = new Date();

var link = document.getElementById("image");
link.setAttribute("src","http://cache3-img1.pressdisplay.com/pressdisplay/docserver/getimage.aspx?file=6107"+d.toMyString()+"00000000001001&page=1&scale=67");

var link = document.getElementById("link");
link.setAttribute("href","http://www.pressdisplay.com/pressdisplay/pageview.aspx?issue=6107"+d.toMyString()+"00000000001001");

</script>
```

In BODY:

```
<center>
<img id="image" width="300">

<br/>

<a id="link" href="#">Read Today Epaper 
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
var months = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember'];
var myDays = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jum&#39;at', 'Sabtu'];
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var thisDay = date.getDay(),
    thisDay = myDays[thisDay];
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
document.write(thisDay + ', ' + day + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + year);
//-->
</script></a>
</center>
```

DEMO:

http://www.epaper.pustakakoran.com/thejakartapost/

How to change that's code to yesterday's date in image url and link url? Thank for all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add number of days to today's date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

Answer (score 0):

Together your code

I used `-1` to get yesterday's day and date

Here is the code that you needed.

```
<a id="link" href="#">Read Today Epaper 
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
var months = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maret', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Agustus', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Desember'];
var myDays = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jum&#39;at', 'Sabtu'];
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var thisDay = date.getDay(),
    thisDay = myDays[thisDay];
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;

document.write(thisDay + ', ' + day + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + year);

//-->
</script></a>
</center>

<a href='#'>Read <script>
var previousday = date.getDate()-1;
var Yesterday = date.getDay(),
    Yesterday = myDays[Yesterday-1];
var values = Yesterday + ', ' + previousday + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + year; 
document.write(values);
</script>
</a>
```

To have it in a image url and link url

```
<a href='thegotjavascriptvaluehere'>
<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/large-glossy-svg-icons/512/go_back_next_arrow_previous-512.png' height="30px" width="30px">
</a>
```