# How to decrement dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, decrement

I have 2 dates: startDate= 6/22/2015 and endDate= 6/20/2015.
I need to decrement these 2 dates, i meen endDate-startDate, so in this example I will get 2.

How can I do this in sql?

Comment: You've mentioned both jquery and sql server in tags, so are you trying to subtract dates by jquery or by sql server?

Comment: Ah ok - you **don't mean** decrement, really - you mean find the **difference** (in days)  between those dates - right?

Comment: No, I need to decrement between them. What if the dates are: startDate= 6/29/2015, endDate= 7/2/2015? not just days.

Answer (score 1):

The native way to do this would be to use the setDate method.  There is an existing Stackoverflow post here: [How to Add Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

However, I always pass along the advice to use a date library, something like moment.js.  In most languages, managing dates (timezones, leap years, etc ets) is incredibly difficult, and javascript can be even more so with browser time zone behaviors.