# Add days, weeks, months to date using jQuery

Tags: jquery, date

I have a form which lets the user select an invoice date and payment terms. The payment terms are; 1 week from invoice date, 4 weeks from invoice date, 1 month from invoice date, etc.

When the user has selected an invoice date and the payment terms I then want to generate the invoice due date.

My question is, how do I add to a date in jQuery and how do I do it in a reliable way. For example, taking into account leap years and the varying number of days in each month. For example, adding 1 month to October 31st should be November 30th and not November 31st.

I have found a few solutions by searching Google but they seem to fail on leap years, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Comment: have you look at javascript date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is not for DateTime manipulation. It's for querying and manipulating DOM objects. For what you need, you can either implement that yourself, or use a specialized third-party library.

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is pretty neat.

Examples:

```
moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar(); // 06/12/2015
moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar();  // Last Tuesday at 1:51 PM
moment().subtract(3, 'days').calendar();  // Last Friday at 1:51 PM
moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();  // Yesterday at 1:51 PM
moment().calendar();                      // Today at 1:51 PM
moment().add(1, 'days').calendar();       // Tomorrow at 1:51 PM
moment().add(3, 'days').calendar();       // Thursday at 1:51 PM
moment().add(10, 'days'
```

More examples here: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript have default date obj you can use as such. moment.js is a neat choice too.

```js
    var date = new Date();

    // add a day or anyday you like 
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

    document.write(date);
```

Comment: Exact, I need to precise that, in javascript, january is the month "0" and december is counted as "11".

Comment: date.getMonth(); will return month as number, jan will be 1, dec will be 12 but you can always `-1`. to get base 0.

Comment: sorry, javascript month is already base 0, so no math needed... disregard comment before.