# Sum date with number of days in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a date `2015-12-22` and i have a field to input number of days `EX: 5` and i want to show result in other textbox `2015-12-22 + 5`. Please give me any solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Answer (score 0):

you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ,it is a very complete library, with several interesting features,Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in javascript.