# how to add n days and n months to current date in javascript

Tags: javascript

Current code by using date.js

`<script>`

`var dd=Date.today().addMonths(3);`

`</script>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need date manipulation, I use [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)