# Display "End Date" based on datepicker "Start Date" and inputted date

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

**Need answer as soon as possible!**

How to get a end date based on a inputted day interval and start date like if i have a start date that has a value of `4/19/2015` and the then the inputted day interval is like `10` how would I do that in jquery and the event will trigger if the value inside the **datepicker** input box changed.

Guys I will appreciate all your help T_T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may refer to the answer [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

Assuming, you are using jqueryui datepicker. if so, use following code to get the selected date, as soon as the date is selected from the datepicker.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var startDate = selectedDate; // you got the startDate here
      }
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

please find the solution below:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="start-date-picker" />
<input type="text" id="end-date-picker" />
```

JS:

```
$('#start-date-picker').datepicker();
$('#end-date-picker').datepicker();


$('#start-date-picker').change(function(){
    var interval = 10;

  function convertDateString(p) { return (p < 10) ? '0' + p : p; }

  var startDate = new Date($(this).val());
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + interval);
    $('#end-date-picker').val(convertDateString(startDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + convertDateString(startDate.getDate()) + '/' + startDate.getFullYear());
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/v6pLmgot/)