# JavaScript How to get date in yyyy/mm/dd format + 14 days

Tags: javascript, date

I have tried to get the current date, which works with the following code:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
console.log(today);
```

Result:

```
2016-12-14
```

But now I want to add 14 days, which works and will display

```
2016-12-28
```

But when I want to add 21 days, the days will go up to 35 so the result will be:

```
2016-12-35
```

Which of course is not a correct date. So how do I get the date in yyyy/mm/dd format + 14 days but the yyyy/mm being correct?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Comment: `But when I want to add 21 days, the days will go up to 35` - no, it wont, if you add the days to a Date object

Comment: add number of days after stetement var today = new Date();
like 
today.setDate(today.getDate()+14)

Answer (score 0):

```
var days=2;

date.setTime( date.getTime() + days * 86400000 );
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Use *setDate*, not time, since not all days are 24hrs long in all time zones.