# Date calculate MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, mean-stack

I'm building a system that need user to pick a date. And from that date I need to add few more days for certain purposes.
Theses are the user's input:

```html
<input type="date" ng-model="req.pickup_date" required>
<input type="number" min="1" max="60" ng-model="req.days" required>
```

So how do I do something like this in the correct way?

```js
var c = 86400000;
$scope.req.return_date = new Date($scope.req.pickup_date + (2 * c));
```

Comment: You could do something like `function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getUTCDate() + 3
}`

Comment: can you write base on my code? I don't really understand how to apply your solution.

Comment: Refer to the days you want to add as + ( $scope.req.days and * whatever )

Comment: Use moment.js:  https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer here : [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

You can use this code:

```
$scope.req.return_date = new Date($scope.req.pickup_date);
$scope.req.return_date.setDate($scope.req.return_date.getDate() + $scope.req.days);
console.log($scope.req.return_date);
// req.days has been added to the return date
```