# please explain my error in this javascript date math

Tags: javascript, date-math

Here's the output from the Visual Studio Immediate Window.  I start with `mondaysDate`, create a second date, `thisDate`, and then add integers to it using mondaysDate as the base.

I don't understand why adding 3 to the date yields November 2 and adding 4 to the date yields December 4th.

Is it illegal to invoke setDate() more than once?

```
?mondaysDate
Mon Oct 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

?thisDate
Mon Oct 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

?thisDate.setDate(mondaysDate.getDate() + 3)
1509595200000
?thisDate
Thu Nov 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)


?thisDate.setDate(mondaysDate.getDate() + 4)
1512363600000
?thisDate
Mon Dec 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

?mondaysDate
Mon Oct 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: When you say `date + 3`, do you mean add 3 days, 3 months, 3 years?

Comment: I'm assuming it's adding days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: I'm expecting November 3 not December 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that first time you add `33 days` from Oct 1, then you add `34 days` from Nov 1.

```
thisDate.setDate(mondaysDate.getDate() + 3)
// You set the date to 30 + 3 (33) days from the first day of the current month (Oct 1)
// Oct 1 + 33 days = Nov 2
// thisDate = Thu Nov 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

thisDate.setDate(mondaysDate.getDate() + 4)
// You set the date to 30 + 4 (34) days from the first day of the current month (Nov 1)
// Nov 1 + 34 days = Dec 4
// thisDate = Mon Dec 04 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

The date is set relative to `thisDate`, starting at 1st of the current month, and adds the day number in `mondaysDate` + 4 days. Every time you call `setDate`, you update `thisDate`.

You can read more about setDate on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

Comment: Why isn't the first call adding 33 days?

Comment: @Patrick Evans: If it is adding 33 days to October 30, why does it say November 2?

Comment: @Tim, Check the MDN link that Cristy has attached. `The setDate() method sets the day of the Date object relative to the beginning of the currently set month`.