# How to add 30 days to Current Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add 30 days to today date and here how i tried Thanks in advance!

```
var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").value = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: `new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60  * 24 * 30))`

Comment: You did right, but months numbering is from 0 to 11. So, to get current month you need to add 1. To get next month you should add 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) and [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193)

Comment: Stack Overflow has been around for more than a decade and 1.8 million javascript questions have been asked. Do you really think nobody has come with a question about adding x days to a date? Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30); // add 30 days 
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Your code might solve the problem but you should always leave a comment on why this solves the OP's problem, keep in mind that the reason we aim to help others is also to educate them.

Answer (score 0):

### Try adding this

add 30 days to todays date: `var now = new Date(); now.setDate(now.getDate() + 30);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30); // Set current date + 30 days as the new date
console.log(date);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date; // to set the value to HTML
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i want to display this date in Text field in Html can you please help me @Tanveer Singh Bhatia

Comment: Your code might solve the problem but you should always leave a comment on why this solves the OP's problem, keep in mind that the reason we aim to help others is also to educate them.

Answer (score 0):

With [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) that would be:

```js
const date = moment().add(30, 'days');
console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `moment.js` library.

it is simple yet powerful library for dates.

```
const moment = require('moment');
console.log(moment().add(30, 'days'));    // 2019-07-28T06:31:28.803
```