# Get date of exactly 6 days ago from today in JS

Tags: javascript, date

Thank you in advance

I would like your help with getting **'days ago'** from a particular `date`. I don't want to use any library.

Although I have tried `moment JS`.

Comment: The logic here would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Comment: have you even tried looking for the solution? `new Date(new Date().getDate()-days*24*60*60*1000)`

Comment: @AZ_—you might want to try running that to see what happens…

Comment: how about you tell me what happens?

Comment: If you insist… `new Date().getDate()` will return a number from 1 to 31. Assuming *days* is 6 then `days*24*60*60*1000` is equivalent to 6*8.64e7. So the result is a date for sometime around 26 December, 1969, depending on the date it's run.

Comment: @RobG typo needed to use `getTime()`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getDate()` and subtract the number of days from it

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 6);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Wow Great. Thanks. How would I do the same for Weeks, Months and Years

Will it still be the same format?

Comment: Month and year are the same for weeks you have to subtract number of weeks*7 from the days like above

Comment: @ellipsis for months you cant do `months*30`

Comment: No you cant. It is valid for weeks only. Not all months have 30days

Comment: @ellipsis that's what I said with less explanation, on your comment `Month and year are the same for weeks `

Answer (score 0):

First, make a new Date with your date:

```
const date = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
```

Second, subtract 6 days like so:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 6);
```

Third, use `date.toString()` :

```
console.log(date.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You question title and description contradict with each other.
The following function that return number of days ago can help if this is what you need:

```
function getDaysAgo(date, now = new Date()) {
    //first calculating start of the day
    const start = now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //then calculating difference in miliseconds
    const diff = start - date.getTime();
    //finally rounding to a bigger whole days
    const result = Math.ceil(diff/(1000*60*60*24));
    //as a bonus returning today/yesterday/future when necessary
    if (result < 0) {
        return 'in future';
    }
    if (result === 0) {
        return 'today';
    }
    return result === 1 ? 'yesterday' : result + ' days ago';
}
```

For example getDaysAgo(new Date(Date.parse('2019-9-28 23:59')), new Date(Date.parse('2019-9-30 10:59'))) returns **2 days ago**.

Comment: Date.parse is redundant in `new Date(Date.parse('2019-9-28 23:59'))` and some browsers treat '2019-9-28 23:59' as an invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple function that returns a new desire past date.

```
function getNthDate(nthDate){
   let date = new Date();
   return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - nthDate))
}
```

Live [example](https://codepen.io/ptheodosiou/pen/gOYJJJd)