# What am I doing wrong. I want to display the date without timestamp but add 50 days

Tags: javascript

```js
var d = new Date(),
datestring = '';

datestring = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate()+

d.setDate(d.getDate() + 50);
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = d;
```

```html
<p>Your estimated date for completion will be </p>


<p id="new"></p>
```

Newbie here. Trying to display the date without time and add 500 days. 
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You need to compute datestring after calling setDate. Something like this d.setDate(d.getDate() + 50);
datestring = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate()
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = datestring;

Comment: please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show only the date then it will be like following,

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 50);
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var date = d.getDate()+' '+months[d.getMonth()]+', '+d.getFullYear(); 
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = date;
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't get that to work, I added to my page , but it won't display the date !

Comment: do you have <p id="new"></p> in your page? also I have added the initial code that was present in your previous code. You need to add var d = new Date(); first.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var today = new Date();
alert("Today = " + today.toLocaleDateString());
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
var date = new Date();
date = today.addDays(5)
alert("After 5 days = " + date.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: hi Thameem Thank you. How do I get rid of the alert commands and get it to display on the screen?

Comment: 1. Create any text element in your html code like span, p, h1-h6 ...
2. Assign an id to that element
3. use "document.getElementbyId("YOUR_ELEMENT_ID").innerHTML = YOUR_VALUE"

I think you should go with this link =>
https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: That's ok No Problem.